# How to create animations like the ones in Photo Booth?

Tags: ios, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I am a beginner in the world of Objective-C, and for my first iOS application, I thought I'd create one similar to Photo Booth. Now, I've done some tinkering with CABasicAnimation, and I was wondering whether there was one which makes the previewlayer, or the camera feed, twirl like "Twirl" does in Photo Booth. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not animations from CoreAnimation, they're filters. They are the CoreImage Filters (or `CIFilter`s). You can [read about them here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html).